# Is it unsafe to travel to Greece at this time?

Tags: europe, greece

Would it be unsafe to travel to Greece at this time?

Comment: @Willeke good point.  Perhaps this is a topic for meta.

Comment: To the OP: why are you questioning safety, and what aspect of safety do you mean? Are you asking if it is personally physically safe to visit Greece? or are you asking if your money and tickets are safe (due to the economic meltdown and potential (withdrawal or removal) from the EU?